# Uploading image link to firestore in swifui

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to firebaseStorage and get the link to it in a buy and sell app in **swiftui**

This is the main function I wrote

```
func uploadPhoto() {
        
        // Make sure that the selected image poperty isn't nil
        guard selectedImage != nil else{
            return
        }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        //Turn our image into data
        let imageData = selectedImage!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        
        guard imageData != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        // Specify the file path an name
        let path = "images/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
        let fileRef = storageRef.child(path)
        
        // Upload that data
        let uploadTask = fileRef.putData(imageData!) { metadata, error in
            if error == nil && metadata != nil {
                
                fileRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                    guard let url = url, error == nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    let urlString = url.absoluteString
                    print("Download url: \(urlString)")
                    self.imageUrl = urlString
                    let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore()
                    firestoreRef.collection("users").document().setData(["items": urlString])
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my addData function:

```
 // Add data
        func addData(items: Items) {
            if let currentUser = currentUser {
                do {
                    try db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).updateData(["items": FieldValue.arrayUnion([Firestore.Encoder().encode(items)])])
                } catch {
                    print("Error occured retriving data")
                }
            }
        }
```

but the problem is when I try to upload/reference the link to the image on firestore It doesn't work.

I'm sending it like this
Here is the **Model **

```
struct UserData: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var items: [Items]
    
}

struct Items: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var price: String
    var description: String
    var image: String?
}
```

and here is how I send it

```
VStack (spacing: 25){
     Button {
      if selectedImage != nil {
         uploadPhoto()
                        }
      if title != "" && price != "" && description != ""  {
         viewModel.addData(items: Items(title: title, price: price, description: description,   image: imageUrl))
                        }
                        
   } label: {
     Text("Publish").font(.buttonTitle)
    }.buttonStyle(CustomButton())

}
```

I tried to send it like I described above but I am getting this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxHkE.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100564/how-to-use-downloaded-url-correctly-in-asyncimage/74117007#74117007

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not simply calling the Firestore API to write the data in the same code block as you set `self.imageUrl = urlString`? That'll make the flow much easier: if the image shows in the UI, it'll also be sent to Firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I clearly see no reason but how should I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. Did you try putting the code that calls the Firestore API to write the data right after that `self.imageUrl = urlString` line? What happened when you did that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wrote this line after `self.imageUrl = urlString`
`let dbRef = Firestore.firestore()`
`dbRef.collection("users").document().updateData(["items": urlString])`
and here is my addData func:
`func addData(items: Items) {
        if let currentUser = currentUser {
            do {
                try db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).updateData(["items": FieldValue.arrayUnion([Firestore.Encoder().encode(items)])])
            } catch {
                print("Error occured retriving data")
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: getting this error:
[FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (129c211a8) Stream error: 'Not found: No document to update: projects/buy-and-sell-ea25e/databases/(default)/documents/users/Q7iZerWYCbMv52ILRW3h'

Comment: Oof... that's a bit hard to parse. It looks like you're trying to update a document that doesn't exist yet, in which case you should use `setData` instead of `updateData`. If that's not clear, can you edit your question to include the updated code and error message at the bottom.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Now I replaced ùpdateData` with `setData` but I get a new document. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a new document for every call is here

```
firestoreRef.collection("users").document().setData(["items": urlString])
```

Every time you call `document()` without any parameter, it generates a new document. To prevent that you need to pass the UID in that `document()` call, in this case with the UID of the user, just as you already did in the call where you called `updateData`: `db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid)`.

So combined:

```
firestoreRef.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).setData(["items": urlString])
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but not the way I wanted. It's still not inside of my items array it is outside of it.

Comment: Is there a way to put the `downloadURL` in a local variable.  like if I have 
`@State var imageUrl = ""` and put the `downloadURL` into it?

Comment: If your `items` field is an array, and you want to add an item to it, have a look at [adding items to or removing them from an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) in the documentation. I do recommend spending some more time in the documentation in general though. This may be a single use-case for you, but by now we're on to the problem in various API calls which makes it really hard to answer in a way that is also useful to future visitors.

Comment: I have spent alot of time on documentetion and there is nothing that could help me. My  `Items` is an array and by using `FieldValue.arrayUnion` this is going to add the `urlString`in my `Items`array but not inside of map in my `Itmes` array.

Comment: We've moved far along from "it doesn't work" and "Not found: No document to update: projects/buy-and-sell-ea25e/databases/(default)/documents/users/Q7iZerWYCbMv52ILRW3h", and are now onto a new problem of updating an item in an array. I recommend focusing your question so that there's a single reusable answer that satisfies it.