# Update an image stored on Firebase in my SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to retrieve an image that's stored in firebase. My device uploads a new photo every 30 seconds to firebase with the same name, overwriting the previous image with a new one. My code retrieves the image and displays it but it doesn't update it until the app is quit and rerun. Is it possible to update it automatically everytime the image is overwritten in Firebase?
Here's my code:

```
@State var retrievedImages = [UIImage]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
            HStack {
                ForEach(retrievedImages, id: \.self) { image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                }
            }.onAppear{
            retreivePhotos()
        }
    }

func retreivePhotos() {
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("images").addSnapshotListener {query, error in//.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
        if error == nil && query != nil {
            var paths = [String]()
            
            for doc in query!.documents {
                paths.append(doc["url"] as! String)
            }
            for path in paths {
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
                let fileRef = storageRef.child(path)
                
                fileRef.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    
                    if error == nil && data != nil {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data!){
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                retrievedImages.append(image)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't listening for changes to `Storage` try using the `url` instead and using `AsyncImage` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100564/how-to-use-downloaded-url-correctly-in-asyncimage/74117007#74117007