# Firebase is not saving the data - swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I have a problem that Firebase not saving the data and it shows like that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQwBS.png)

First I created a model :

```
struct Box: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var boxName: String
    var boxSize: String


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case boxName
        case boxSize

      }

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
            let data = (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)) ?? Data()
            return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]
        }

}
```

Then I created ViewModel:

```
class BoxViewModel: ObservableObject {


    @Published var box: Box
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()


    init(box: Box =  CashBox(boxName: "", boxSize: "")) {
        self.box = box

    }

    private func addNewBox(_ box: Box){

        do {


            print("the name  \(box.boxName)")

            let _ = db.collection("Box")
                .addDocument(data: box.dictionary)


        }
    }


    func addBox() {
        self.addNewBox(box)

    }
    
    
    func setBoxData(boxName: String, boxSize: String){
        
        self.box.boxName = boxName
        self.box.boxSize = boxSize
    }
}
```

Finally here is the view:

```
struct CashBoxView: View {

    @State var boxName = ""
    @State var boxSize = ""

    @EnvironmentObject var boxViewModel: BoxViewModel


    var body: some View {

        Text("Enter box name")
        TextField("", text: $boxName)

        Text("Enter box size")
        TextField("", text: $boxSize)

        Button( action: {
           boxViewModel.setBoxData(boxName: boxName, boxSize: boxSize)
           boxViewModel.addBox()
        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }

}
```

First I thought that the problem is the box is empty but when I tried to print the box name `print("the name \(box.boxName)")` and printed it

is the problem the the viewModel is `@EnvironmentObject`  ? or what is the problem ?

Thank you,

Comment: You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100564/how-to-use-downloaded-url-correctly-in-asyncimage/74117007#74117007) sample, it is a bit more involved but the `FirestoreService` has samples on how to update and retrieve using the object itself, the issue is likely in all the ignoring (`try?`) that you are doing, Firebase does all the work for you don't try to recreate

Comment: Just a question: Is the goal to write encoded serialized JSON data to Firestore? It may be a good idea to take a look at [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) and also [Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects).