How to update Firebase Storage URL before displaying items in SwiftUI View
I'm retrieving list of exercises from Firebase and filtering it. After that I need to make  another async request to resolve video URL and update it (see code below). The issue is that exercises are returned to the view before the URL is resolved. How to fix it?
import Combine
import FirebaseStorage
import Foundation

class ExerciseViewModel<DS: DataService>: ObservableObject where DS.Item == Exercise {
    @Published var exercises: [Exercise] = []

    private let dataService: DS
    private let storage = Storage.storage(url: "someURL")

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(dataService: DS, idArray: [String]) {
        self.dataService = dataService
        dataService.getData()
            .sink { error in
                print("Exercises request failed: \(String(describing: error))")
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] data in
                Task {
                    self?.exercises =
                        await self?.filterExercises(exercises: data, by: idArray) ?? []
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private func filterExercises(exercises: [Exercise], by idArray: [String]) async -> [Exercise] {

        var filteredExercises = exercises.filter { idArray.contains($0.id ?? "") }
        filteredExercises.forEach {
            var exercise = $0
            Task {
                do {
                    exercise.videoUrl = try await self.storage.reference().child(
                        "video/\(exercise.video ?? "")"
                    ).downloadURL().absoluteString
                    print("Video URL resolved: \(exercise.videoUrl ?? "")")
                } catch { print("Error resolving video URL: \(error)") }

            }
        }

        return filteredExercises
    }
}


Not a Swift expert, but in most languages your code is awaiting the absoluteString property, where you actually should be awaiting the (async) downloadURL() call. If that's indeed the problem, try (await self.storage.reference().child("video/\(exercise.video ?? "")").downloadURL()).absoluteString (so with an extra pair of parentheses.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100564/how-to-use-downloaded-url-correctly-in-asyncimage/74117007#74117007

usually if you are using sink something has gone wrong

Updated code to make it work:
init(dataService: DS, idArray: [String]) {
    self.dataService = dataService
    dataService.getData()
        .sink { error in
            print("Exercises request failed: \(String(describing: error))")
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] data in
            Task {
                self?.exercises = await self?.filterExercises(exercises: data, by: idArray) ?? []
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

private func filterExercises(exercises: [Exercise], by idArray: [String]) async -> [Exercise] {
    let filteredExercises = exercises.filter{idArray.contains($0.id ?? "")}
    var result: [Exercise] = []
    for exercise in filteredExercises {
        let videoUrl = await getVideoRef(exercise.video ?? "")
        var updatedExercise = exercise
        updatedExercise.videoUrl = videoUrl
        result.append(updatedExercise)
    }
    return result
        
}

private func getVideoRef(_ video: String) async -> String {
    do {
        let videoURL = try await storage.reference().child("video/\(video)").downloadURL().absoluteString
        return videoURL
    } catch { return "" }
}

